# finding if part of a word is in values of a python dictionary

Tags: python, json

After parsing a json file which contains names and ages of people,

```
{"People":
    [
        {  "name":"damon julian",
           "age":40
         }
    ]
}

data=json.load(file)
d1=data["People"][0]
```

I got a dictionary like this

```
d1={'name':'damon julian','age':40}
```

I want to find out if the substring `'damon'` exists in one of the values in the dict.So I tried

```
[(k, v) for (k, v) in d1.iteritems() if 'damon' in v]
```

However this would give an error

```
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

I solved this by casting the value as a string

```
[(k, v) for (k, v) in d1.iteritems() if 'damon' in str(v)]
```

I would like to know if there is a better way to do this.Is my approach of converting the `json data to dict` and then parsing the values correct?Or is there a better way-may be using regular expressions or something?

Please advise.

Comment: Do you *really* need to look at *all* entries of the dict, or would the `name` value suffice?

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want to locate and return the field that contains your name, or just return True if it exists?

Comment: need to return the field if the condition matches

Comment: This is not really "casting" (Python does not have such a thing), but "conversion". Anyway, if you only need to check the name field, then why not *only check the name field*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
any(('damon' in v) for v in yourDict.values() if isinstance(v,str))
```

or

```
any((isinstance(v,str) and 'damon' in v) for v in yourDict.values())
```

(do note that both of these constructions are not always equivalent)

Comment: This throws an exception just like his first attempt.

Comment: `isinstance` is a filtering condition, so put it in the `if` clause of the generator expression.

Comment: Filtering conditions work a little differently in `any()` and `all()`; this should not be a filtering condition.

Comment: Though in this particular case, I believe it works as a filtering condition (and I may change it for readability), since ignoring a value in `any(...)` is equivalent to pretending it is False.